# Expand selection (Ctrl +) to the specified direction in edit mode?

Tags: selection-tools

It would be very handy to have an option to expand/contract a selection not in all directions only, but also to a specified one. Or to limit the selection in other way.

Is it doable in blender? Or any addons?

Here is an example (manually done) of what i would like to achieve.

[image: selection growth in one direction only]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've selected a pair of elements which bear some logical relation to one another ( e.g. along a loop, along a ring, every other along a ring ) then [Select Next Active](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#more-less) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad+</kbd>) makes a pretty good job of carrying on the sequence you started.