# How do you Select Next Active (CTRL+SHIFT+Numpad+) w/ Bisected Section?

Tags: selection-tools, bisect

I've seen the thread on doing a `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`Numpad+` in "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106493/expand-selection-ctrl-to-the-specified-direction-in-edit-mode" but i'm not sure if it's possible with the below scenario when you make a bisection and try to select one bisected area or only a portion of it with `CTRL`+`Numpad+`. My current workaround is to set the bisection line edges with `Make Seam` and then do `L` to select an area and then `Clear Seam`. But sometimes i want to gradually select only a few segments, not the entire bisected area. Is there a way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Hello, you say "i want to gradually select only a few segments, not the entire bisected area", waht segments are you talking about and how Blender would be able to guess what segments you want?

Comment: when u press numpad+ it will select the next faces in both directions along the loop's normal. so that works. we know there are only 2 directions it goes. since there are only 2 possible directions along the loop normal i was thinking maybe blender has some logic implemented where we could choose a direction with a certain shortcut key to go in one direction (+) and another shortcut key to go the other direction (-) or something.  so i was curious to know if there was any secret trick.